# How to combine two pretrained models in keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I would like to combine two pretrained models(DenseNet169 and InceptionV3) or it could be any two. Followed the steps from the following link, but did not work. Did try both concatenate and Concatenate, still getting error. I might have made some mistakes somewhere. This is my first stackoverflow question and help would be greatly appreciated.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39407/how-to-make-two-parallel-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras
First case: I tried with NO pooling

```
model1 = DenseNet169(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(300,300,3))
out1 = model1.output    

model2 = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(300,300,3))
out2 = model2.output

from keras.layers import concatenate 
from keras.layers import Concatenate 

x = concatenate([out1, out2])  # merge the outputs of the two   models
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)  # final layer of the network
```

I got this error:

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 9, 9, 1664), (None, 8, 8, 2048)]

Second case: tried with average pooling, able to concatenate but got error in training process

```
model1 = DenseNet169(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg', input_shape=(300,300,3))
out1 = model1.output   

model2 = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg', input_shape=(300,300,3))
out2 = model2.output

x = concatenate([out1, out2])  # merge the outputs of the two models
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)  # final layer of the network

model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=[out])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(generator=data_generator_train,
                          validation_data=data_generator_val,
                          epochs=20,
                          verbose=1
                         )
```

Error in second case:
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[0.17074525, 0.10469133, 0.08226486],
         [0.19852941, 0.13124999, 0.11642157],
         [0.36528033, 0.3213197 , 0.3085095 ],
         ...,
         [0.19082414, 0.17801011, 0.15840226...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Second Case:** Since your model expects two inputs, your `data_generator_train` and `data_generator_val` should return/yield a list of two inputs for corresponding models and output. You can achieve that by updating the return value of `__data_generation` method

```
def __data_generation(...):
    ...
    # consider X as input image and y as the label of your model
    return [X, X], keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

**First Case:** Since the spatial size of the output of model2 `(8x8)` is dissimilar (smaller) to model1 output `(9x9)`, you can apply zero padding on model2 output before concatenation.

```
out1 = model1.output
out2 = model2.output
out2 = ZeroPadding2D(((0,1), (0,1)))(out2)
x = concatenate([out1, out2])
```

For first case too you need to modify your data generator like second case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Greatly appreciated. 
I used class DataGenerator from 
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly,
still don't quite understand how to fix
'def __data_generation' part to arrive at [X, X, y].
Still got the same error in training process.Please do help me fix this issue.

Comment: Try with `return [X, X], keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)` in `__data_generation` method. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Second Case Structure is True, but consider that you concatenate two models and each model has its own input if the input is similar for both of models just fit the model by repeat the input like this:

```
model.fit([X_train,X_train], y_train)
```

I myself implement your problem and it works absolutely well.

```
model1 = DenseNet169(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
model2 = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

model1_out = model1.output
model1_out=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model1_out)

model2_out = model2.output
model2_out=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model2_out)

x = concatenate([model1_out, model2_out])

x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x) 

model=Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input],outputs=x)

model.fit([X_train,X_train], y_train)
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Greatly appreciated. 
I tried your method. it works fine for fit but still got the same error for fit_generator. Is there any that works for fit_generator as well?